# Remove the period and everything after it using jQuery

Tags: jquery, string

Is there a way to remove the period and everything after it using jQuery? The numbers following the period vary in length, so it's not as simple as finding the length.

For example:

```
<span class="changethis">505.234</span> <span class="changethis">23.93</span>
```

Thanks for your help!

P.S. (bonus) If there is a way to round up if it's x.5 or higher that would be awesome. Not essential though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('.changethis').each(function () {
    $(this).html(Math.round(parseFloat($(this).html())));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d4fv8/1/

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick (including rounding):

```
$(function() {
  var element = $('.changethis'); 
  var number =  parseFloat(element.html());
  element.html(number.toFixed(0));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the contents of the spans will only ever be numeric then this will do what you need:

```
$("SPAN.changethis").each( function(index, elem) {
    $(elem).text(Math.round($(elem).text()))
});
```

The first selector gets all the spans, then iterate over each span replacing its contents with the result of Math.round() of its contents.

Answer (score -1):

The Javascript to handle the truncation and rounding is built in to the language, no jQuery needed:

x=Math.round(505.234)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Comment: jQuery would come handy when selecting the DOM element and getting/setting it's text. Perhaps you can update your solution to do that.

Comment: I suppose I could, but someone already did - I was reading the question as if the author was thinking there was a jQuery function that does what Math.round() does, and was only pointing out that "remov[ing] the period and everything after it using jQuery" was the wrong avenue to pursue, although on reflection I see that I should have also included the jQuery part.